# Unable to add new custom module to magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml

I am trying to add a new module to magento admin panel by following this article

http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited
When I have added all the files correctly, on clearing cache, admin panel goes **Blank** , I have an other magento setup, when I move the same files to that set up, new module is created. What is issue in 1st set up, due to which I am unable to create a new module.

Comment: Did you checked error log for old installation?

Comment: Yes, nothing there, even no exception

Comment: Did you enable error log from admin?

Comment: got following error

Comment: 2016-01-12T11:20:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/www/ABC/includes/src/XYZ_Adminhello_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /www/ABC/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: and next was this

Comment: 2016-01-12T11:20:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/www/ABC/includes/src/XYZ_Adminhello_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/www/XYZ/includes/src:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/lib/php')  in /www/ABC/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: It means you have not created helper file in **Helper** folder of your module? Create Data.php file

Comment: I have created this file '<?php
class XYZ_Adminhello_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}    '

Comment: Added helper tag in config.xml?

Comment: Then your helper class should be Sbux_Adminhello_Helper_Data, Not XYZ_Adminhello_Helper_Data

Comment: Yes as you can see '    <global>
        <helpers>
            <abc_adminhello>
                <class>XYZ_Adminhello_Helper</class>
            </abc_adminhello>
        </helpers>
    </global>'

Comment: Disable compilation from your admin *System > Tools > Compilation*. And then check

Comment: Got it, thankx, if you can put your last comment as answer, I will accept it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable compilation from your admin `System > Tools > Compilation`

Create helper file in your module **/XYZ/Adminhello/Helper/** directory as **Data.php**

Put following code in it.

```
class XYZ_Adminhello_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
```

Hope it helps you